# How to disable windows live id login for domain connected clients

Tags: windows-8, login, domain

Is there a way to disable the option to login via windows live id on domain connected computers on Windows 8?

There seems to be a way to switch between trying to login with domain credentials vs windows live id. The user needs to press a key icon to switch between the 2 modes. This is very confusing for my users as we only use domain credentials and they keep trying to login the wrong method. I would like only the option to login with domain credentials presented.

Comment: My questions is how to disable the ability to try to login with Microsoft accounts.

Comment: I have revised the answer

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**
> The following steps require creating **.reg** file and editing your registry.
>
> "Microsoft Accounts" in Windows 8 and 8.1

**To completely block the usage of Microsoft Accounts for all users.**

1. Open Notepad and Add

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]`

`"NoConnectedUser"=dword:00000003`

2. Save it as .reg file to the desktop.
3. If prompted, click/tap on Run, Yes (UAC), Yes, and OK.
4. When finished, you can delete the  .reg file if you like.

*To Allow Microsoft Accounts*

```
"NoConnectedUser"=-
```

*Users can't add Microsoft Accounts*

```
"NoConnectedUser"=dword:00000001
```

*Users can't add or Sign in with Microsoft Accounts*

```
"NoConnectedUser"=dword:00000003
```